# How to use Oracle hints or other optimization to fix function in where clause performance issue?

Tags: oracle, optimization, plsql, database-performance

This is slow:

```
select col_x from table_a where col_y in (select col_y from table_b) and fn(col_x)=0;
```

But I know that this will return 4 rows fast, and that I can run fn() on 4 values fast.

So I do some testing, and I see that this is fast:

```
select fn(col_x) from table_a where col_y in (select col_y from table_b);
```

When using the fn() in the where clause, Oracle is running it on every row in table_a. How can I make it so Oracle first uses the col_y filter, and only runs the function on the matched rows?

For example, conceptually, I though this would work:

```
with taba as (
   select fn(col_x) x from table_a where col_y in (select col_y from table_b)
)
select * from taba where x=0;
```

because I thought Oracle would run the with clause first, but Oracle is "optimizing" this query and making this run exactly the same as the first query above where fn(col_x)=0 is in the where clause.

I would like this to run just as a query and not in a pl/sql block. It seems like there should be a way to give oracle a hint, or do some other trick, but I can't figure it out. BTW, table is indexed on col_y and it is being used as an access predicate. Stats are up to date.

Comment: What kind of function is `fn`? If called with the same parameter multiple times, does it always return the same value?  If so, can you define the function as deterministic and then create a function-based index on it?

Comment: Hi sstan, no it is not deterministic. It is a complex function and has a cursor in it.

Comment: Consider also `MATERIALIZE` hint: https://dbaora.com/with-clause-and-hints-materialize-and-inline/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you could go around it,

1) add 'AND rownum >=0' in the subquery to force materialization.

OR

2) use a Case statement inside the query to force the execution priority (maybe)

Comment: Hi Arcan3, Thanks for your answer. #1 works. I didn't try #2 since I wasn't sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but if anyone has a better answer, please share:

```
select col_x
from table_a 
where col_y in (select col_y from table_b) 
  and (select 1 from dual where fn(col_x)=0);
```

Kind of kludgy, but works. Takes a query running in 60+ seconds down to .1 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `HAVING` clause in your query. This clause is not executed until the base query is completed, and then the `HAVING` clause is run on the resulting rows. It's typically used for analytic functions, but could be useful in your case.

```
select col_x 
from table_a 
where col_y in (select col_y from table_b) 
having fn(col_x)=0;
```

> A HAVING clause restricts the results of a GROUP BY in a
>   SelectExpression. The HAVING clause is applied to each group of the
>   grouped table, much as a WHERE clause is applied to a select list. **If
>   there is no GROUP BY clause, the HAVING clause is applied to the
>   entire result as a single group.** The SELECT clause cannot refer
>   directly to any column that does not have a GROUP BY clause. It can,
>   however, refer to constants, aggregates, and special registers.

http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj14854.html

Comment: I tested that, and it works nicely too. It also requires a "group by col_x" so it isn't super clean (especially with my actual table that has lots of columns), but it's a smart idea.

Comment: @BobThule Yeah, according to the docs a group by isn't required, but in my experience it is required sometimes. I haven't quite figured out the rules for when it's required or not - probably depends on how the query is structured.

Answer (score 0):

1) Why you don't try join table_a and table_b using col_y.

```
  select a.col_x from table_a a,table_b b
    where a.col_y = b.col_y
     and fn(col_x) = 0
```

2) NO_PUSH_PRED -

```
 select /*+ NO_PUSH_PRED(v) */ col_x from (
    select col_x from table_a  where col_y in (select col_y from table_b) 
   ) v 
   where fn(col_x) =0
```

3) Exists and PUSH_SUBQ.

```
select col_x from table_a a 
    where exists( select /*+ PUSH_SUBQ */ 1  from table_b  b where a.col_y = b.coly )
     and fn(col_x) = 0;
```

Comment: Hi Arkadiusz, 
Thanks for your answer.
1) My example was only trying to show that I had an access predicate for col_y. Depending on the query, I would do a join, but I would generally always prefer ANSI join syntax.
2) I was excited about this, because it was the kind of answer I was looking for-- but it still ran the query very slow.
3) Sadly, my example was a contrived version of a more complex query, and I am unable to translate this to the complex query.